# Problem in fetching .net web service when hosted on server

Tags: c#, web-services, asmx

I hosted a Web service(http://monocept.net/vlt/html/AutoComplete.asmx) and running it using IIS 7.0 Win server 2008. In other web application I am trying to access this web service. When I am accessing this service it throws exception as

> HTTP 404. The resource you are looking
>   for (or one of its dependencies) could
>   have been removed, had its name
>   changed, or is temporarily
>   unavailable.  Please review the
>   following URL and make sure that it is
>   spelled correctly.

But this same service working fine when I am running in local machine.

Comment: Can you browse to the web service in a browser?

Answer (score 0):

Can you browse to the url of your asmx directly? eg http://myremoteserver/app/service.asmx

Check the asp.net feature is installed in IIS. Check the app is assigned to an app pool of the right version (v2, v4, etc). It shouldn't matter whether you use integrated pipeline or classic. As a service, you probably want to make sure anonymous access is configured.

Simon

Comment: Yes I am able to browse to my asmx(http://monocept.net/vlt/html/AutoComplete.asmx) directly, but when I am giving inputs to the service it throws exception.

Comment: Yes I am able to browse to my asmx(http://monocept.net/vlt/html/AutoComplete.asmx) directly, but when I am giving inputs to the service it throws exception.How to check asp.net feature is installed and how to see anonymous acess is configured @Simon Halsey

Comment: If you're seeing the info page for the service then you have .net installed. You can find out using the server manager. Anonymous access will be defined in your web.config, under authentication & authorization, although those look ok too as I can browse your service. Perhaps it down to the path with the operation to run not being picked up properly. Sorry I can't be more help.